# How to define a contract that allows either a quoted list or a function?

Tags: racket

I have a function whose single argument can be one of:

- quoted list (which I will `eval` within a context)
- function

How to express this as a contract for this argument?

My first guess was:

```
(or/c expr? list?)
```

Any better ideas or this is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `expr?` does not exist, you should either use `procedure?` or something using the arrow constructor (for example `(-> number? any/c)`) for the function part of the contract.

Moreover, since this is a contract for a *function*, you should include both domain and range using `->`.

Example:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/contract)
(require rackunit)

(define/contract (f x)
  (-> (or/c (-> number? number?) list?) (or/c number? list?))
  (if (list? x)
      x
      (x 3)))

(check-equal? (f '()) '())
(check-equal? (f add1) 4)
```